# Tailwind CSS - Styles not being applied

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a project that uses Tailwind CSS and Next.JS, though I'm running into a problem in which some Tailwind classes are not taking any effect? An example would be adding a `bottom-0` class, which has no effect but `right-0` does work.

```
<div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0">
```

Disabling JIT does fix the issue, but I would like to keep this enabled and understand what the issue really is.

Here is the screenshot of the issue and my tailwind config file for your reference.

[image: screenshot]

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    screens: {
      xs: '480px',
      // => @media (min-width: 480px) { ... }

      sm: '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      md: '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      lg: '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      xl: '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

      '2xl': '1536px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
    },

    extend: {
      flex: {
        half: `0 0 50%`,
      },
      animation: {
        loader: 'loader 0.6s infinite alternate',
      },
      keyframes: {
        loader: {
          to: {
            opacity: 0.1,
            transform: 'translate3d(0, -1rem, 0)',
          },
        },
      },
      fontSize: {
        // [ FontSize, Line Height]
        xs: ['11px', '14px'],
        sm: ['13px', '18px'],
        lg: ['15px', '22px'],
      },
      fontFamily: {
        montserrat: ['Montserrat', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif],
        'montserrat-semibold': [
          'Montserrat-semibold',
          ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif,
        ],
      },

      colors: {
        orange: {
          DEFAULT: '#f07e22',
          darker: '#d7690f',
          lighter: '#f29040',
        },
        inputGrey: {
          DEFAULT: '#F5F6F7',
        },
        success: {
          DEFAULT: '#F8FCEE',
          border: '#c9decb',
        },
        body: {
          DEFAULT: '#1B1F2A',
        },
        warning: {
          DEFAULT: '#FEF7F2',
          red: '#BF2424',
        },
        orderStatus: {
          DEFAULT: '#FFF',
          warning: '#FFFBED',
          warningBorder: '#FFEB9B',
        },
        borderGrey: {
          DEFAULT: '#E2E3E4',
        },
        footerBlue: {
          DEFAULT: '#1C2E61',
        },
        facebookBlue: {
          DEFAULT: '#1978f2',
        },
      },
    },

    container: {
      center: true,
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['checked'],
      borderColor: ['checked'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can i know the path of your component from root of your project, it could be purging issue

Comment: It's just components/account/Dropdown.js.

Comment: What version of `tailwindcss` are you using?

Comment: I'm running Tailwind CSS version 2.2.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen as a result of Tailwind optimisation algoritm (it removes unused classNames).

1. I faced simillar behaviour: in `className="absolute m-6 text-soft"` `m-6` did not applied it styles.
   I use monorepo, and this styles are applied to component from `root/packages/ui`. This component was imported to `root/app/web`.
   As Tailwind can't find this classNames 'as a text' in `root/app/web` (because the text are in `root/packages/ui`) - it simply do not add them to build.
2. One more case I faced with some months ago - setting part of style as a variable.

   `const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) -> <div className='m-{n}' />`

That code will can also cause the same behaviour (missing styles) as Tailwing can not read styles strings.

Your case may be slightly different, but the core reason can be same - **Tailwind do not compile your styles as think that they are unused as can not read them.**